# What can't I print out the value of a instance attribute derived from other instance attributes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, instance-variables, derived-attribute

I'm pretty new to Python and I would be really grateful if someone could help me out with this issuer I'm facing.

This is my code:

```
class Player:
def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.info = {}
    self.info_count = len(self.info)



tom = Player("tom")
tom.info["Name"] = "tom"
tom.info["Height"] = "167cm"
print(tom.info)
print(tom.info_count)
```

**Output**

```
{'Name': 'tom', 'Height': '167cm'}
0
```

I am trying to get an instance attribute that automatically saves the number of info I have. Why is the output still 0 when I have 2 info in the info variable? Thank you!

Comment: You set `info_count` to the length of `info` when `info` was empty. That is zero.

Comment: `__init__` function sets the length of the `info` in line, where you are creating a new instance of the class. Then you add some things to `info` but the `info_count` won't update. That's Python classes basics, I think you should learn more about that before posting this question.

Comment: Thank you.  Now I understand where I went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You first set `info_count` to 0, but then it isn't modified anymore, you assign a **value** not a *link to some property of info dict*.

```
init            -> info={}                                info_count=len(info)=0
info["name"]    -> info={'Name':'tom'}                    info_count = 0 
info["Height"]  -> info={'Name':'tom', 'Height':'167cm'}  info_count = 0
```

---

What you need is a  [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property)

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.info = {}

    @property
    def info_count(self):
        return len(self.info)


tom = Player("tom")
tom.info["Name"] = "tom"
tom.info["Height"] = "167cm"
print(tom.info)       # {'Name': 'tom', 'Height': '167cm'}
print(tom.info_count) # 2
```

Comment: Ahhh now I understand where I went wrong. Thank you so much!